# How to bind the CanExecute value of a command to a MultiDataTrigger condition in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Please see **Edit 3** for updated summary.

---

I'm working on a WPF Prism application with a view that has a `Grid` element that should only be visible if any one of three commands is returning `true`. Right now I've gotten it working by creating a `bool` property for each command that returns whether or not it's possible to activate, though I shouldn't be doing that as it's duplicating what the command can do.

Here's the XAML I have right now:

```
<Grid x:Name="OptionsContainer">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=CanSaveUser}" Value="false" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=CanUndoAll}" Value="false" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=CanDeleteUser}" Value="false" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>

    <!-- Elements nested in this grid go here. -->

</Grid>
```

This is working, but I can't figure out a way to convert it to use a command instead. I've been searching over the past two days and haven't come across what I'm looking for yet, but if there are existing resources please feel free to point me in their direction!

**EDIT**: Here's what my implementation of a `Condition` looked like using a command. This was a best guess on my part as to what I thought it would look like.

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding Path=SaveUserCommand, Converter={StaticResource InvCmndToBool}, ConverterParameter=InvertFalse}" Value="false" />
```

**EDIT 2**: I realized it'd be best to include the converter I'm calling in the first edit I made. You'll find it below.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(DelegateCommand<object>), typeof(bool))]
public class InvertableCommandToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    enum Parameters
    {
        InvertFalse, InvertTrue
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DelegateCommand<object> command = (DelegateCommand<object>)value;
        bool boolValue = command.CanExecute(null);

        var direction = (Parameters)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parameters), (string)parameter);

        if (direction == Parameters.InvertTrue)
            return !boolValue;

        return boolValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3**: After some more testing I narrowed down the issue to the binding not updating (as far as I can tell) when the respective command's `CanExecuteChanged` event is called. Binding to a bool value that gets updated in the command's `CanExecute(object)` method updates the MultiDataTrigger, but using a command does not. That means that it sets the right value when the view is originally created. Not sure if there's something else I need to be doing to ensure that the command gets called?

You can see my first edit for an example of what I'm using as conditions now.

Comment: Another way is using Multi binding and converters.

Comment: I did try a converter that took the `DelegateCommand<object>` property and returned a bool, but that never got called. I've updated my question with the implementation I used, though this was my best guess at how the set up would look like since I couldn't find any definitive information when I searched.

Comment: Did you try with multi binding ([Multi-Binding Ref](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328978/Introduction-to-multi-binding-and-multi-value-conv)) ? Also there is another option where you could create property in the model that return visibility and directly bind it with Grid Visibility, but you will need to manually set its Property changed whenever any of the linked property is changed (i.e. in your case: CanSaveUser, CanUndoAll, CanDeleteUser)

Comment: @D_Learning: right now it's working if I use the `CanSaveUser`, `CanUndoAll`, and `CanDeleteUser` bools, which I added since the commands weren't working. I'm actually doing what you described in the second part of your response :)  I'm hoping to use commands directly since I feel like I'm duplicating code by having those CanXXXXX bools. Haven't tried multi binding yet, but that's something else to look into. Also added a new edit since I narrowed down where I'm having issues.